# Fetching selection values from a dynamically generated SWT tables

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP app, I have a tab folder widget. Each of the tab items in the tab folder widget holds a single table. The tab items (represent name of a specific hall) are dynamic and whenever a tab item is created dynamically, a table is created to be displayed within that tab item. The tab items are being dynamically created along with the table (and the table's content too) for each item in the tab folder.

Now when I try to retrieve the user selected values in the table in the first (or any other tab except the last one), I'm not able to get the values. I am able to retrieve and manipulate
the table in the last tab item only. It seems like the preceding tables in the preceding tab items are replaced/overlapped by the new tables that are created dynamically later on. How do I solve this?

For Instance,

```
//createPartControl method
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    .....
    .....    

    createTabFolder();
}


// createTabFolder() method
private void createTabFolder() {

tabFolder = new CTabFolder(comMainContainer, SWT.BORDER);
tabFolder.setBounds(204, 21, 769, 495);
    tabFolder.setSelectionBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(
            SWT.COLOR_TITLE_INACTIVE_BACKGROUND_GRADIENT));

    // display the tabitems in the tabfolder dynamically
    try {
        selectedDate = sdf.format(dateChooser.getSelectedDate());
        rs = objHallBookingController.getHallList();

        while (rs.next()) {

            displayCtabItems(rs.getString("hall_name"),
                    rs.getInt("hall_id"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


// displayCtabItems method
private void displayCtabItems(String hallName, int hallId) {

            tabItem = new CTabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tabItem.setText(hallName);

    comTabItem = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tabItem.setControl(comTabItem);


    tblHallBooking = new Table(comTabItem, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    tblHallBooking.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tblHallBooking.setLinesVisible(true);

    tblclmnTime = new TableColumn(tblHallBooking[hallId], SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnTime.setWidth(88);
    tblclmnTime.setText("Time");

    tblclmnTitle = new TableColumn(tblHallBooking[hallId], SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnTitle.setWidth(306);
    tblclmnTitle.setText("Title");

            // display contents in the table; working fine
    displayHallOpeningTime(Integer.parseInt(txtHallId.getText()));
      }
```

This code generates and displays the tab items and the tables. But I can't manipulate the contents in the tables in the tab items other than the last one.

Comment: Could you please make some test case (small app that shows your unwanted behavior)..?

Comment: Pls see the edits, I have added a code sample into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call method `displayCTabItems(...)` more than one time (depends on `rs.next()`)

```
while (rs.next()) {
    displayCtabItems(rs.getString("hall_name"),
        rs.getInt("hall_id"));
}
```

but you creates the Table instance `tblHallBooking = new Table(comTabItem, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);` again and again to same attribute `tblHallBooking`, so in first cycle will have the attribute point to instance of Table in first tab, in second cycle will point to Table on second tab, etc. In every cycle you override value (instance "pointer") to Table on current creating tab.

You have to make Array of tables (size of array equals size of items in list `objHallBookingController.getHallList();`) or you have to dynamically lookup to children of selected CTabItem and search for Table instance..

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, here could be way, how to get your table from selected CTabItem

```
Control parent = tabFolder.getSelection().getControl();
if(parent instanceof Composite) {
    Composite parentComposite = (Composite) parent;
        Control control = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < parentComposite.getChildren().length; i++) {
            if(parentComposite.getChildren()[i] instanceof Table) {
                control = parentComposite.getChildren()[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if(control != null) {
        // now you have your table in control
        Table tbl = (Table) control;
        // do whatever you want with tbl
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to go with your second suggestion and I did sth. like `tabFolder.getSelection().getControl()`. But that would return me a **Composite** only because for each tab item, I have defined a composite and inside that composite only, I have placed the table. Now, how do I get the table? I tried sth. like `tabFolder.getSelection().getControl().moveAbove(comTabItem)` where comTabItem is the name of the composite inside a tab item. But I cant get the table control returned.

Comment: Great... that worked out flawlessly....thank you!! But I must admit that I don't understand that `getChildren()[i]` stuff. I can understand the semantics but don't get a clear insight into this. I would really appreciate for pointers onto this.

Comment: Okey will try..
First, you get your parent control a check if it is Composite (if it is safe to cast `Control parent` to `Composite`.. Then, you can have more than just a `Table` instance on the parent, you can have some other `Label` or `Button` or other control instance on the composite (parent), so you have to iterate on all children (all controls = Tables,Button,Labels, etc, on the Composite parent) and check if one of them is instance of `Table`, if does, you can stop the searching (assumption you have only one Table instance on each parent Composite) and do whatever you need.. Better? ;]

Comment: Yes of course thank you... but specifically I'm talking about the `getChildren()[i] ` method. This method fetches whatever the control is at the _ith_ position right? I'm a bit confused about the way the _ith_ array element is fethced. I have never seen an array element being fetched from a array like that `methodName()[index]`. So I was asking for pointers on that.

Comment: Oh, this one.. method `getChildren()` on any Composite returns array of `Control` instance to who is the Composite parent.. So I could do this `Control[] children = parent.getChildren();` and then `for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {...; children[i]...}`, but it's additional variable, so I just short the code and use array index directly on the result of the method.. You can write `control = (parentComposite.getChildren())[i];` if it's more transparent for you..